# Replace values in dataframe column if second column matches a given list pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
      col1          col2
0     str9          val1
1     str8          val2
2     str4          val3
3     str2          val4
4  unknown1    asdvstr1df
5  random1  teststr2test
```

and the following list

```
strings = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4']
```

I want to replace the value in column 1 if there is a match at any point in the string in column two with the given list, strings.

Note: col2 can have the values of the list 'string' inside the string, or at either end as well.

Currently I am doing this with an ugly and slow nested loop:

```
import pandas as pd

data_file = pd.DataFrame(data = ([['str9', 'val1'], ['str8',  'val2'], ['str4','val3'] , ['str2', 'val4'] , ['unknown', 'asdvstr1df'] , ['unknown', 'teststr2test']] ), columns = (['col1', 'col2']), dtype = str)
strings = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4']

for value in range(data_file.shape[0]):
    for text in strings:
        if (str(data_file.col2[value]).find(text) != -1):
            data_file.loc[value, 'col1'] = text
```

I am unsure how to improve upon this slow process. How can I make this run faster than the current O(nm) time (n is size of the data_file, m the size of the list called strings)?

The output should be:

```
   col1          col2
0  str9          val1
1  str8          val2
2  str4          val3
3  str2          val4
4  str1    asdvstr1df
5  str2  teststr2test
```

Comment: So you want to overwrite unknowns in order with your list?

Comment: The fact that `data_file[4, 'col2']` contains the string `str1` and `data_file[5, 'col2']` contains `str2` is not very clear in the question (I had to manually step into the loop to realize str1 was there). Maybe add that as a comment?

Comment: Yes or perhaps better practice would be to make a new column:

        if (str(data_file.col2[value]).find(text) != -1):
            data_file.loc[value, 'newcol'] = text
        else:
            data_file.loc[value, 'newcol'] = data_file.loc[value, 'col1']

Comment: Also are you only interested in changing `unknown`s (if so you can filter, this would drastically reduce the search space).

Comment: @ayhan making that edit now; and no, column 1 can take on different values (editing that as well).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC,

```
x = '(' + '|'.join(strings)+ ')'
df.assign(col1 = df.col2.str.extract(x, expand=False).combine_first(df.col1))
```

Output:

```
   col1          col2
0  str9          val1
1  str8          val2
2  str4          val3
3  str2          val4
4  str1    asdvstr1df
5  str2  teststr2test
```

Comment: Yep, extract is the way op should use : -)

Comment: @dward4 Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can using `replace` twice with `regex`

```
d1=dict(zip(strings,[1,2,3,4]))
d2=dict(zip([1,2,3,4],strings))

df.loc[df.col1=='unknown','col1']=df.col2.replace(d1,regex=True).replace(d2)
df
Out[970]: 
   col1          col2
0  str9          val1
1  str8          val2
2  str4          val3
3  str2          val4
4  str1    asdvstr1df
5  str2  teststr2test
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data_file["col1"] = data_file["col2"].apply(lambda y:strings[[True if x in y 
else False for x in strings ].index(True)] if any([True if x in y else False 
for x in strings ]) else y)
print(data_file)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   col1          col2
0  val1          val1
1  val2          val2
2  val3          val3
3  val4          val4
4  str1    asdvstr1df
5  str2  teststr2test
```